# ios viewDidLoad is starting up in Portrait - but developing Landscape Apps

Tags: ios

Having ViewControllers is for having good MVC structure.

But when you are developing landscape mode applications, you kind of need to move the ui logic down to a sub UIView.

Reason: When programatically adding UIViews down the line(subviews), you have to wait for didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation to get the right Bounds.

Or am I missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. The only solution that i found is overriding

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

method of the view controller. And layout subviews here.

Comment: Thanks, I will except this - though it is still called each time orientation is changed.

Answer (score -1):

if not i misunderstood your problem, you want  start the application in landscape mode directly on startup. 
try to put  commands on your file app.plist

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply - I have already done this. In viewDidLoad getting the Bounds of the [[self view] bounds] is Portrait. In order to get the right landscape bounds, you need to wait for didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation to happen. I was wondering if you could force this to happen in the viewDidLoad.